# Using HTML5 Canvas Tag on Safari With Large Images

Tags: javascript, ios, html

on safari through iphones I can read an image through js window.FileReader but cannot use the canvas tag in HTML5 due to the image size of standard photos taken by the iphone.

The image can be displayed in  tags but canvas cannot draw these  tags.

I need this to be able to manipulate an image (compress, move, rotate,etc.) 
How can I work around this? Android works fine.